# I am new to arduino please help me in understanding this code

Tags: ethernet-shield

```
while (client.connected()) {
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.write(c);
```

Why we require **char c** and what is the use of using this command **Serial.write(c)**

Comment: how much of the code do you understand?

Answer (score 1):

`client.read()` returns exactly one byte from the serial input buffer for the port connected with object `client`. That is why you use a `char` variable. The name `c` is not relevant.

The next line, `Serial.write(c)` then writes that same character to the main serial port.

The code basically reads from one serial port and writes the same data immediately to the other serial port.

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is simple "Serial pass-thru" code. Whatever a client receives gets printed on the serial terminal.

It can be written, line by line, in English like this:

```
- While the client is connected:
    - If there is some text available in the client:
        - Read one character from the client and store it in the
              variable "c" which is of "char" type.
        - Print that character out to the serial port.
```

The reason you use `Serial.write(c);` is so that you can see what has been received.